# Add spaces in react-hook-forms while typing

Tags: reactjs, forms

I am trying to use react-hook-forms to make a mobile field that (for AUS) is formatted like so:
0412 345 678.

How can I make it so when they type it will input the spaces automatically?
I can get it to make a space at the right times but when they press back space it gets stuck because it reads 3 characters then adds the space as a forth and gets stuck in this loop making it impossible to backspace any more...
Here is the code...

```
<label>
    Mobile*
    <input
        name="mobile"
        type="text"
        onChange={(e) => {
            if (e.target.value.length == 3) {
                e.target.value = e.target.value + ' '
            } else {
                e.target.value = e.target.value
            }
        }}
        ref={register({ required: true })}
    />
</label>
```

Thanks

Comment: Hope this can help: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-input-mask#examples

Answer (score 0):

Presuming that you mean react-hook-form and not react-hook-forms, here's how I did it for a credit card.

```
   const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    setValue,
    formState: { errors }
   } = useForm();

   <input
    className="form-control rounded-right"
    register("txtWalletCardNumber", {
    required: {
     value: true,
     message: "Cardholder name is required"
    },
    maxLength: {
     value: 16,
     message:"Card number may not exceed 16 characters"
    },
    minLength: {
     value: 16,
     message:"Card number may not be less than 16 characters"
    },
    pattern: {
     value: /^[\d+\s]*$/,
     message:"Card number may only contain digits and spaces"
    }
    })}
    onKeyDown={(e) => {
     const backspacePressed = e.key !== "Backspace";
     const currentValue = e.currentTarget.value;
     if (backspacePressed) {
      const lengthNoSpaces = currentValue.replace(/ /g,"").length;
      if (
       lengthNoSpaces !== 0 &&
       lengthNoSpaces % 4 === 0 &&
       currentValue.length < 17
      ) {
         setValue(
          "txtWalletCardNumber",
          currentValue + " "
         );
       }
      } else {
       if (currentValue[currentValue.length - 2] === " ") {
        setValue(
         "txtWalletCardNumber",
         currentValue.substr(0,currentValue.length - 1)
        );
       }
      }
     }
    }
    id="txtWalletCardNumber"
    placeholder="1234 5678 9012 3456"
    type="text"/>
```